# What does the './' do in a command like './manage.py' or './bin/buildout'?

Tags: linux, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “/” , “./”, “../” represent while giving path?](https://superuser.com/questions/153165/what-does-represent-while-giving-path)

Example:
For running a django server I use:
`python manage.py runserver`

But some people seem to use `./manage.py runserver`. This command seems to do the same as the previous one.

What exactly does the `./` part do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` is the path of the current directory.
Every directory always have two special files, `.`, and `..`, where first represents itself, while second represents the parent directory.

By writing `./manage.py runserver`, you are running command `manage.py` with argument `runserver`. To see what happens when you execute `manage.py`, check what is the content of the file with `less manage.py`.

To sum it up, there shouldn't be any difference in both cases, unless the python version stated in the manage.py is different than the default python version. The python used in `manage.py` can be seen at the first line.

Comment: Ok, so the first line of `manage.py` is `#!/usr/bin/env python`. `./file` will always execute the file the binary provided by that path. So it's just better to write `./` then `python` because it's shorter. Correct?

Comment: Bentley, you still don't appear to understand. It's not something you should bear in mind specific to Python. Check my answer.

Comment: Off Course, I just meant in this case but I guess I could've written it more clearly sorry. Could you explain why running `python manage.py` doesn't require `manage.py` to have executive permission while `./manage.py` does?

Comment: Sure, the reason is that running 'python manage.py' doesn't need executive permission on manage.py is : In this case, manage.py is just an argument to command python.

Answer (score 3):

The `./` tells the shell that you are referring to a file in the **current directory.** If you wanted to call a program such as `backup` and this happened to be a binary available in one of the `program directories` on the system, the shell would by default run this binary.

However you might have been in a directory of your own programs which happened to have a binary called `backup`, too. You might hence not even realise that the system was actually running a completely different binary.

By using `./backup`, you are specifying that you want the system to use the binary in the current working directory, as opposed to one available in the program dirs.

You can test this by using the Linux `whereis` command, which in this example might specify that `backup` is actually at `/usr/bin/backup`, instead of perhaps `~/backup`.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for the use of `./` prefix is that the current directory is not in the $PATH variable. At least it shouldn't be, like in windows, where you have a `;.` at the end of the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

`./` is a short hand method of doing an operation from the current directory.

`../` is a short hand method of going "up" a folder before entering the folder name given.

Comment: What do you mean with 'root line'? Operating from  the `/` (root) directory? This doesn't make any sense to me because there is no `manage.py` file in my `/` directory.

Comment: @Bentley4 `./` means the current directory. See the other answers to this and the linked question for details.

Comment: Sorry, root was a bad word choice. Thank you @indrek
Too many "project roots" :(