# Why do I need ./ for commands to run on Mountain Lion?

Tags: mysql, linux, osx-mountain-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “/” , “./”, “../” represent while giving path?](https://superuser.com/questions/153165/what-does-represent-while-giving-path)

Why do I need `./` for commands to run on Mountain Lion?

For example, when using mysql I have to type in the terminal:

`./mysql -u itsme -p`

Also, I'm creating command line applications and make my files executable and I do have to run the command with `./`, like this...

`./myawesomeapp dothis`

I know `./` means current directory, but how can I run commands without having to use it?

Comment: @cdhowie It's a programming question if it arises in building an executable on the command line.

Comment: @Potatoswatter No, it's not. That's flawed logic. I could use that same argument to argue that just about any computer-related topic is on-topic on SO.

Answer (score 6):

If you put the directory with your binaries into your `PATH` environment variable, you can call them without providing the path (ie the `./`)

I'd guess you're probably using bash as your shell (you can check by running `echo $SHELL`). If that's the case, add the following to your `.bashrc`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/whatever/path/you/want/to/add
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to install the executable file in one of the directories listed in the environment variable `$PATH`.

```
echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Adjust `$PATH` by modifying your `~/.profile` file.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/me/bin
```

It is possible to forgo the `./` always by adding `.` to `$PATH`, but that could be a security issue — if not on your personal machine, then when you carry the bad habit over while operating a server.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it is possible to add `.` to your $PATH variable, it is highly recommended NOT to do that. If you walk around to some random place in the filesystem and type something that you think will run a program (`vi`, `emacs`, `ls`, `ps`, etc), a file in the local directory will become a candidate to run. If you are unlucky, that's NOT the program you wanted to run at all - and if you are running as `root`, it's even worse, because someone may well add a local file `ls` that does something completely different than real `ls` (along with doing real ls, of course - otherwise it would be obvious that it's not real ls, and the user would start investigating the situation). [1]

Instead, you should add an absolute path to where you have your executable files, e.g. `/projects/mycurrentprojects/bin` - or "relative to home", e.g. `~/bin` - if you want the path to work in ALL circumstances it's better to use `home\mats\bin` [obviously using the right username for yourself]. That way, only files in a certan set of directories are applicable, and no matter where you are, only programs that are in those specific directories are chosen as "possible candidates to run".

[1] Yes, I realize that the search order and various other factors will also matter here. But it's generally not a great idea to add "current directory", no matter what objections.

Comment: The tilde `~` might not always expand, causing frustration. Its substitution is done by shell programs, while various other kinds of environments may use `PATH`.

Comment: Good point. So may be better to write out `/home/mats/bin` - editing...