# Use of / when using cd

Tags: linux, command-line, mac, terminal

I'm in my home directory on my mac:

```
$ pwd
/Users/lukas
```

When I `cd` around, I do not (and can't) start the path with `/`:

```
$ cd Documents/
/Users/lukas/Documents

$ cd /Documents
-bash: cd: /Documents: No such file or directory
```

Except when I'm in `/`:

```
$ pwd
/
$ cd Users
/Users

$ cd /Users
/Users
```

Why can I use `/` in front of the path when going from `/` to `/Users` but not in any subsequent levels? Is this specific to macOS or is this standard Unix behavior?

Comment: I think questions about relative and absolute paths have been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46121000/what-is-an-absolute-pathname-vs-a-relative-pathname) [befofre](https://superuser.com/questions/153165/what-does-represent-while-giving-path)

Comment: @adamczi It is pretty obvious that OP does not know what a relative path is, or how its syntax is, thus he can't look it up.

Comment: @K.Gkinis Which is not a reason for not closing as duplicate. It help askers to get good answers (assume answers are good) and answerers to maintain less versions of the same content.

Comment: @K.Gkinis And, in a sense, that is a large part of the point of closing as a duplicate: people will ask questions in lots of different ways, so lots of questions (matching those ways) pointing to a single answer is a Good Thing. In cases like this (where an OP doesn't know the term to search for), closing-as-dupe is not a criticism of them, just the best way of handling the many way people ask questions.

Comment: generally we use ./ but it is redundant.  as would be ~/

Comment: @adamczi They have been asked before (thank you for the links!) but my question and especially the great answers given here are _way_ more detailed and explain the concept better than the answers you linked. Don't know if that matters for closing as duplicate, but might be a consideration.

Comment: I totally understand that it's hard to search when you don't know what the term is, but I still stand for "this could be really easily searched for" - [this](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=XcU&channel=fs&ei=Pob2W4MUkbWwB57RntAI&q=linux+paths+beginning+with+slash&oq=linux+paths+beginning+with+slash) returns [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607413/when-to-use-a-preceding-slash-in-path-names-e-g-for-the-cd-command) as the first result with even more complete answer.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is standard Unix behaviour.

The `/` at the beginning of the path represents the root of the disk (or the start/uppermost level of the filesystem tree).  As `Documents` is not off the root, `/Documents` can't be found.

`/Users` is off the root directory, so this problem does not occur.

You could use `cd /Users/lukas/Documents` to change to that path.

Alternatively, you could use relative addressing.  Unix based filesystems have 2 special directories:

- `.` which means "this directory",
- `..` which means the parent directory.

If you are in `/Users/lukas`, `cd ./Documents` would take you to the correct place.

Let's assume you were in `/Users/Lukas/Documents` and wanted to go to `/Users/Janes/Documents`, you could issue a command `cd ../../Janes/Documents` - using `..` would take you back a level - so you would do it twice, before going into the new relative path.

Comment: Note: as @davidgo said, when in `Users/lukas`, `cd Documents` calls for the _relative path_; `cd /Users/Lukas/Documents` calls for the _absolute path_ (which would be working whatever repertory you are in when calling this command).

Comment: While the question is about a Mac, which is a Unix system, this is also standard MS-DOS/Windows behavior (replacing `/` with `\\`) since DOS borrowed it (through a long, convoluted history)  from Unix.

Comment: Also depending on the shell you use, cd $HOME/Documents or cd ~/Documents would also work. The shell variable HOME (accessed with $HOME) is the usual storage location for your home directory (~ being a special alias for $HOME).

Answer (score 13):

`/Users/lukas` is an "absolute" path. The leading `/` represents the root directory of your filesystem.

`lukas` is a "relative" path. As it is not anchored to the root, it means "look for this in the *current* directory". Unless the current directory is `/Users` (or some other directory with a `lukas` in it), this will fail.

So, let's explore your examples, assuming you're in `/Users/lukas`:

```
$ cd Documents/
/Users/lukas/Documents
```

Relative path given => change to the directory "Documents" that's inside `/Users/lukas`.

```
$ cd /Documents
-bash: cd: /Documents: No such file or directory
```

Absolute path given => change to the directory `/Documents`.

```
$ pwd
/
```

This shows that you've now changed the working directory to the root directory, `/` (though the `cd` command to do this was not shown).

```
$ cd Users
/Users
```

Relative path given => change to the directory "Users" that's inside `/`.

```
$ cd /Users
/Users
```

Absolute path given => change to the directory `/Users`.

The key each time is that leading `/`. With it, the path is absolute. Without it, the path is relative. This rule is unambiguous because all absolute paths begin with `/` (because the root directory is always called `/`).

Here's some pseudocode loosely describing that algorithm:

```
MakePathAbsolute(path):
   if <path> starts with '/'
      return <path>
   else
      return <current directory>/<path>
```

The argument you pass to `cd` goes through this algorithm; the directory you end up changing to is the path that the algorithm returns.

---

Further reading:

- **[Unix Files and Directories Tutorial](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~zachary/isp/tutorials/files/files.html)**
  Joseph L. Zachary
  *"Introduction to Scientific Programming"*

Comment: This is also a _great_ walk-through and really helps in understanding this behavior. Thank you! :)